# Clamav Error Internal Logger

Tags: logging, clamav

I am running this cron job

```
30 01 * * * /usr/bin/freshclam --quiet; /usr/bin/clamscan --recursive --no-summary --infected / 2>/dev/null
```

but i am receiving a daily email with error:

```
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
```

I can't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
lsof | grep freshclam.log
```

will give you the details on which program/process is using this file.

Comment: I am only getting one process: freshclam 1506          clamav    3wW     REG              253,1    50034    1055269 /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log

Comment: Do you also get the error, when the job is not executed by cron, but when you do it manually?

Comment: Maybe you could use the following command to debug the problem: `/usr/bin/freshclam --verbose --debug > /tmp/freshlcam.log 2>&1`  or send the output to a different logfile: `/usr/bin/freshclam --quiet --log=/var/log/clamav/freshclam-cron.log`

Comment: Today i also got an out of memory notification at the time the cron job started at var/log/syslog: Out of memory: Kill process 1419 (clamd) score 400 or sacrifice child

Comment: I guess the question becomes: do i really need to run this cronjob? Isn't clamav always running on the background and actively detecting  threads? It's taking too much memory as it is...

Comment: To be honest, the question might also be: Is clamav good enough to use it? Does it reliably detect current threads? I doubt it and that's the reason why we have been using commercial solutions for our clients for years now.

Comment: hi stefan, could you please recommend a better alternative?

Comment: I don't use the server to receive any emails. Only outgoing emails through postfix which goes through google apps antivirus anyway. Server is Ubuntu 16

Comment: Well, we are either using Kaspersky or ESET, depends on what the customer wants to use on the desktop. We then take the other product for the server.